# last_ddl_time in dba_objects table Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl

what does column "last_ddl_time" in table "dba_objects"  really mean? what causes the change of the date in this column?

We are testing this as part of change management in Oracle and im not sure what this column really represents.

Thank you in advance!

regards

Comment: According to the comment on the column itself: "Timestamp for the last DDL change (including GRANT and REVOKE) to the object"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs:

> Timestamp for the last modification of the object resulting from a DDL
>   statement (including grants and revokes)

So creating a table, altering a table, rebuilding an index, granting access and so on and so forth, depending on the object type.

Did you have a more specific question, or was that it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! is it possible to find out whether these "changes" were caused by application itself or by DBA?

Comment: Not without auditing